# sharepoint 2010 dataformwebpart drop down list filter

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-designer, dataformwebpart

I have two connected DataFormWebparts on a site page, with one web part filtering the data in the other, and this works fine as long as the design style allows the options to be clicked on i.e. the information is laid out in text format.

However If I change the style to be a drop down list then the filtering no longer works. I'm assuming this is because there is no longer a hyperlink to trigger off the event, but is there a way to make it work in this format?

Answer (score 0):

jquery to the rescue. hide the links. show the dropdown and with jquery or javascript, trigger the link click on dropdown index change. try to google out. hope these hints help

faced same issue. i did this as i had less time